# Using callgrind/kcachegrind to get per-thread statistics

Tags: multithreading, valgrind, kcachegrind, callgrind

I'd like to be able to see how "expensive" each thread in my application is using callgrind.  I profiled with the `--separate-thread=yes` option which gives you a callgrind file for the whole app and then one per-thread.

This is useful for viewing the profile of any given thread, but what I really want is just a sorted list of CPU time from each thread so I can see which threads are the the biggest hogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valgrind/Callgrind doesn't allow this behaviour. Neither kcachegrind does, but I think it will be a good improvement. Maybe some answers could be found on their mailing-list.

A working *but really boring* way could be to use option `--separate-thread=no`, and update your code to use for each thread a **different** function name or class name. Depending your code complexity, it could be the answer (using 1computeData(), 2computeData(), ..)

Comment: Yeah, this is about the same conclusion I've reached.  Guess it's a good idea for an open source contribution!

Answer (score -2):

Just open multiple profiles in kcachegrind at the same time.